# css background not working in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background

I have a little problem with my code but I can't find where is the issue.
If I use a backgraund in css with the "body" tag, it shows, but if I do the same with a div, it remains in white.

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="one">
        <header>
        </header>
        <section>
        </section>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
#one{
    background: url(../img/background.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

and a javascript (just incase)

```
$(function(){
    var x = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
        x-=1;
        $('body').css('background-position', 0 + 'px '+ x +'px');
    }, 200);
})
```

I tried with the 'body' and it works, but only with the body :(

Comment: Why don't you show your failing attempt??? Maybe i miss understand your issue. Is it related to CSS or js or both?

Comment: Seems like it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/4eweL11j/. Have you debugged at all? Is there any errors in the console?

Comment: Give height and width in `px` in `#one{...}` css

Comment: Seems like you are miising CSS rule: `html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}`  Otherwise your DIV wouldn't have any size defined:**EDIT:** @RoryMcCrossan Oh ya, just see your jsFiddle ;)

Comment: Css i gues. i don't have any report from the console, the background just is not shown, is only seen when using the "body" tag in css

Comment: @ithan Maybe that helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16871236/why-doesnt-html-and-body-take-all-available-height-of-document-when-min-height

Answer (score 0):

To use 100% height in your `#one` div you need also to set 100% height for your `body` and `html` tags. 100% width will work without this rule.
So add the following line to your css file:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the complete HTML are you trying with? In the code you give us, your `div` doesn't have size because it doesn't have content. In the snnipet you can see your code with content added to the `div#one`.

A ramdom googled image is used as background for testing purposes
.

```js
$(function(){
        var x = 0;
        setInterval(function(){
            x-=1;
            $('body').css('background-position', 0 + 'px '+ x +'px');
        }, 200);
    })
```

```css
#one{
    background: url(http://7-themes.com/data_images/out/76/7030767-3d-background-wallpaper.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="one">
            <header>
              <p>Sample Header</p>
            </header>
            <section>
            </section>
            <footer>
            </footer>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```